# Kotlin room database crash on kotlin 1.2.40 version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

after upgrading to kotlin 1.2.40 I have the following error at build:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/serialization/jvm/JvmProtoBufUtil
at me.eugeniomarletti.kotlin.metadata.KotlinClassMetadata$data$2.invoke(KotlinMetadata.kt:51)
at me.eugeniomarletti.kotlin.metadata.KotlinClassMetadata$data$2.invoke(KotlinMetadata.kt:50)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
at me.eugeniomarletti.kotlin.metadata.KotlinClassMetadata.getData(KotlinMetadata.kt)
at android.arch.persistence.room.ext.KotlinMetadataProcessor$DefaultImpls.getParameterNames(KotlinMetadataProcessor.kt:33)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor.getParameterNames(PojoProcessor.kt:73)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor.getParamNames(PojoProcessor.kt:245)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor.chooseConstructor(PojoProcessor.kt:263)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor.doProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:207)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor.access$doProcess(PojoProcessor.kt:73)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor$process$1.invoke(PojoProcessor.kt:104)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor$process$1.invoke(PojoProcessor.kt:73)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.cache.Cache$Bucket.get(Cache.kt:46)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.PojoProcessor.process(PojoProcessor.kt:101)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.EntityProcessor.doProcess(EntityProcessor.kt:68)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.EntityProcessor.access$doProcess(EntityProcessor.kt:50)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.EntityProcessor$process$1.invoke(EntityProcessor.kt:57)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.EntityProcessor$process$1.invoke(EntityProcessor.kt:50)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.cache.Cache$Bucket.get(Cache.kt:46)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.EntityProcessor.process(EntityProcessor.kt:56)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.processEntities(DatabaseProcessor.kt:248)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:63)
at android.arch.persistence.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:53)
at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:57)
at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:318)
at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:131)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1039)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1180)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:87)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:45)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:257)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:212)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:95)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:405)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:920)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:950)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:404)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.jvm.JvmProtoBufUtil
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 77 more
```

After I changed to version 1.2.30 in my build-gradle the build worked, but now I have a mismatch between the version used by gradle (1.2.30) and the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.2.40).

Is there anything I am doing wrong with the new kotlin version ? Or how can I downgrade to the 1.2.30 version ?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: The issue is tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78328708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downgrade by downloading a plugin zip corresponding to your android studio version here: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

And use `Settings | Plugins | Install plugin from disk` and select the downloaded zip file.

Comment: Thank you. Worked. But I still wonder what went wrong with the kotlin 1.2.40 version.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. In fact I did tried some minutes to find how to solve this under 1.2.40, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that they've introduced a binary incompatibility in `compiler-embeddable` in Kotlin `1.2.40`. There're a few options right now:

1. Downgrade Kotlin to the `1.2.30`
2. Use the latest Kotlin version with the **stable** Room version (`1.1.0`). Then you must substitute the `kotlin-compiler-embeddable` dependency (see below).
3. Use the latest Kotlin version with the **latest** Room version (`1.1.0-rc1`). They've fix bug in RC1.

I'd use the 3d way and keep an eye on the Room's releases. But if you choose the 2nd one then you must insert this in your **root** `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency {
                if (requested.name == "kotlin-compiler-embeddable") {
                    useVersion("1.2.30")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated to 1.1.0-rc1 and kotlin 1.2.41 but Room started to complain about closed database after a migration, which was working fine before the update. I returned again to Room 1.1.0-beta2 and kotlin 1.2.30 and all is working fine.

Comment: What about the 2nd approach? Does it work? I think it's not applicable to the original issue though. You can create another SO question about that.

Comment: Didn't try the second option, since downgrading to Room beta2 and kotlin 1.2.30 is working well, as far as I can see it.